# How can I use recursion to make consecutive axios calls if the response contains 50 ids?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a function that cycles through an array of URLs with a page number and I'm expecting the response to contain 50 ids maximum. I'd like to return the ids or increment the page counter until response returns less than 50 ids. The code saved below is two separate parts and the Request function is the section not working correctly.

I'm using axios to call the server, but I get the error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning"

```
let urlArr = [
      'https://restapi.com/token=TOKEN_ACCESS&usr=Fred&page=', 
      'https://restapi.com/token=TOKEN_ACCESS&usr=Skip&page='
];
let users = [];
let promises = [];
let pageCounter;
for (var i = 0; i < urlArr.length; i++) {
   pageCounter = 0;
   promises.push(
         users.push(this.Request(urlArr[i], pageCounter))
    )
}
Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log(users));

Request:(url, pageCounter)=>{
      return axios.get(url+pageCounter).then(response => {
            let itemCounter = 0;
            let arr = [];    //Not sure if this array is needed
            response.data.forEach((item)=>{
                itemCounter++;
                arr.push(item.id);
                if(itemCounter == 50){ //If counter equals 50 go to next page
                    pageCounter++;
                    return Request(url, pageCounter)
                }
                return arr;  //return an array with ids
            });            
        });    
}
```

I expect the output to be an array filled with ids ex: [1, 2, 3]

Comment: Are you just trying to get all the results from single data source? If not, what are the values in `urlArr`?

Comment: Btw, you can edit your question to include the values in `urlArr` instead of answering in the comments.

Comment: I added two examples about how each URL appears.

Comment: So are you just trying to get all the results for a set of users?

Answer (score 1):

It is a common request to keep asking how many records exist, as it makes it hard to know when the service offers no page info at all, for example

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 3,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 4
}
```

for this particular issue, you only have one solution: Keep asking the service for records until it gives you no more...

so the problem now is how you will get recurring data, and the flow could be something like:

1. request data per page
2. for each response, check if the data returned is "full"
3. if not, append the page counter and goto 1

in Javascript, using Axios and ES6 you can easily do this in no time using the `async/await` as you need to wait until the request is processed in order to check the response, for example, and using [Regres.in Fake API](https://reqres.in/) you would end up with

```
const Axios = require('axios');

const API = 'https://reqres.in/api';
const MAX_PAGE = 3;
const COUNTER_START = 1; // for this fake api, paging starts with 1

const getAll = async () => {
    let pageCounter = COUNTER_START;
    let isProcessing = true;

    while (isProcessing) {
        const json = await getPagedData(pageCounter); // get data
        isProcessing = !isFinished(json.data); // check data
        pageCounter += 1; // increase page counter
    }
}

const isFinished = data => data.length !== MAX_PAGE;

const getPagedData = page => Axios.get(`${API}/users?page=${page}`).then(res => {
    //console.log(`### [ PAGE ${page} ] ###\n${JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 4)}`);
    console.log(`### [ PAGE ${page} ] ### -> returned ${res.data.data.length} objects`);
    return res.data;
});

getAll();
```

and you would have something like

```sh
node .\index.js
### [ PAGE 1 ] ### -> returned 3 objects
### [ PAGE 2 ] ### -> returned 3 objects
### [ PAGE 3 ] ### -> returned 3 objects
### [ PAGE 4 ] ### -> returned 3 objects
### [ PAGE 5 ] ### -> returned 0 objects
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to write this so you can run the code here. So I'll write a function that simulates the `axios.get` function. It just returns a Promise with a value that's similar to the the value `axios.get` resolves to.

```js
//
// the functions below are here to help simulate the axios request
//

// creates a random number to use as an ID
const randomInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min

const createRandomRecords = (num) => {
    let results = []
    
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        results.push({
            id: randomInt(1, 2000),
        })
    }
    
    return results
}

// this function simulates an axios request
const axiosGet = (url, pageNumber) => {
    // let's just say this will return 50 records for the first 3 pages, then return 34 records
    const numRecords = pageNumber < 4 ? 50 : 34

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve({
            data: createRandomRecords(numRecords)
        }), randomInt(100, 300)) // a random interval
    })
}

//
// everything that follows is the problem you're trying to solve
//

// gets all the records for a single user
const getAllRecords = (baseUrl, resultsPerPage, pageNumber) => {
    const pagedUrl = `${baseUrl}&page=${pageNumber}`

    return axiosGet(pagedUrl, pageNumber)
        .then(axiosResults => {
            // more results
            if(axiosResults.data.length === resultsPerPage) {
                return getAllRecords(baseUrl, resultsPerPage, pageNumber + 1)
                    .then(getAllRecordsResults => ([...axiosResults.data, ...getAllRecordsResults])) // combine the two result arrays into one
            }
            // this is the last page of results
            else {
                return axiosResults.data
            }
        })
}

const urlArr = [
    'https://restapi.com/token=TOKEN_ACCESS&usr=Fred', 
    'https://restapi.com/token=TOKEN_ACCESS&usr=Skip',
]


// a really easy way to transform an array of one thing into an
// array of another thing is Array.map. You can lookup how it works.
Promise.all(urlArr.map(url => getAllRecords(url, 50, 1)))
    .then(recordsPerUser => {
        // these are your final results
        console.log(recordsPerUser)
        
        // if you want just the ids
        return recordsPerUser
            .map(records => records.map(record => record.id))
    })
    
    .then(idsPerUser => {
        console.log(idsPerUser)
    })
```

One caveat with this solution is that it will potentially run **a lot** of requests at the same time. The service you are querying may not allow that many requests at once. You will potentially have to do some kind of rate limiting.

Also, here's a pretty good explanation of the `Array.map` function: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d